# Resolving hierarchy in a database table

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have an org chart table which is modeled like this:

```
+-------------+------------+-----------------+
| Employee_ID | Manager_ID | Department_Name |
+-------------+------------+-----------------+
|           1 |          2 | Level1          |
|           2 |          3 | Level2          |
|           3 |            | Level3          |
+-------------+------------+-----------------+
```

So, each employee refers to another row, in a chain which represents the org chart. With all employees, this model is used to represent the hierarchy.

However, for reporting purposes, we'd need to query a denormalized table, i.e. where the data is represented like this:

```
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Employee_ID | ORG_1  | ORG_2  | ORG_3  |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
|           1 | Level1 |        |        |
|           2 | Level1 | Level2 |        |
|           3 | Level1 | Level2 | Level3 |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

with an many ORG_x columns as needed to represent all levels that can be found. Then you can do simple groupings such as GROUP BY ORG_1, ORG_2, ORG_3. Note that one could reasonably assume the maximum number of levels.

So here's my question: since the database sits on SQL server, can I expect this to be feasible in Transact-SQL so that I could build a view?

Before I start learning T-SQL, I want to make sure I'm on the right track.

(BTW, if yes, I'd be interested in recommendations for a good tutorial!)

Thanks!

R.

Comment: You may need to consider your design a little more; what happens if someone adds a row where Manager_id=3 and Department_Name = 'Level 4'. You may to do a bit more normalisation

Comment: Funny, I would expect a different report.  With ID 3 having 1 level (he/she is the boss because no manager), and ID 1 having 3 levels (he/she is an under-under-ling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [common table expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Employee_ID int,
    Manager_ID int,
    Department_Name varchar(10)
);

INSERT @T VALUES
(1,2,'Level 1'),
(2,3,'Level 2'),
(3,NULL,'Level 3');

WITH C AS (
    SELECT Employee_ID, Manager_ID, Department_Name
    FROM @T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.Employee_ID, T.Manager_ID, C.Department_Name
    FROM C
    JOIN @T T ON C.Manager_ID=T.Employee_ID
), N AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_ID ORDER BY Department_Name) N, *
    FROM C
)
SELECT Employee_ID, [1] ORG_1, [2] ORG_2, [3] ORG_3
FROM N
PIVOT (MAX(Department_Name) FOR N IN ([1],[2],[3])) P
ORDER BY Employee_ID
```

**Result:**

```
Employee_ID ORG_1      ORG_2      ORG_3
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           Level 1    NULL       NULL
2           Level 1    Level 2    NULL
3           Level 1    Level 2    Level 3
```

*Note: If you have only 3 levels, you can also do simple 3 x JOIN*

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually didn't expect to be given the query. This is really great!

Comment: I've been trying unsuccessfully to apply your query to my real-life case. I don't need to a create table and populate it, so what part of it do I replace with my actual table name? Do I need to keep the "@"? I'll try and learn some basics of t-sql, but I could already learn a lot from this example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes the pattern you have here is known as an adjacency list. It is very common. The downside is that build your tree requires you to use recursion which can lead to performance problems on large sets. Another approach that is a lot faster is to use the [Nested Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) model. It is a little less intuitive at first but once you understand the concept it is super easy.

No matter which model you use to store your data it is going to require a dynamic pivot or a dynamic crosstab to get it in the denormalized format you need.

Comment: Sure, with a Nested Set it's easier and faster to get all the subgroups of a group. But it's also harder to maintain. And there's no direct method to assign a sub-group to multiple groups.  For most organizations that fine because for most there's only 1 department per employee. But I doubt all organizations can be defined by the limitations of a nested set.

Comment: @LukStorms I would disagree that nested sets is harder to maintain, in fact it is quite simple. But agree you can't have a single member belong to multiple branches. But to be fair once you belong to multiple branches it is no longer a true hierarchy, but is pretty common in a number of situations.

Comment: OK, but I wouldn't advice a Nested Set for the employees anyway.  Employees are added or removed or switch department all the time. But if it's just to define the relations of the branches/departments? That's less volatile in nature (in most organizations anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I think it's probably worth for me to get a few notions of T-SQL.

Comment: Nested Sets are the way to go.   Especially with larger hierarchies and data sets.